# "The transaction under which this method call was executing was asynchronously aborted" when creating page in XPM

Tags: experience-manager, 2013-sp1, session-preview

Trying to create a Page out of Page Type in XPM gives the following notification:

**The transaction under which this method call was executing was asynchronously aborted**

Details:

```
Server stack trace: 
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.ThrowIfFaultUnderstood(Message reply, MessageFault fault, String action, MessageVersion version, FaultConverter faultConverter)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at Tridion.Web.UI.Models.SiteEdit.FastTrackPublishingService.IFastTrackPublishingService.Preview(PublishedItemInfo[] publishedItemsInfo, String publishingTargetId)
   at Tridion.Web.UI.Models.SiteEdit.Services.FtpPreview(PublishedItemInfo[] publishedItemsInfo, String publicationTargetId)
   at Tridion.Web.UI.Models.SiteEdit.Services.CreateNewPageImpl(String pageTypeId, String title, String fileName, String locationId, String publicationTargetId, String viewUrl, Dictionary`2 clonedComponentTargetLocationOverrides)
   at Tridion.Web.UI.Models.SiteEdit.Services.CreateNewPage(String pageTypeId, String title, String fileName, String locationId, String publishingTargetId, String viewUrl, Dictionary`2 clonedComponentTargetLocationOverrides)
   at SyncInvokeCreateNewPage(Object , Object[] , Object[] )
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)
   at Tridion.Web.UI.Core.Extensibility.DataExtenderOperationInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)
```

This seems to be dependent on a page size being created, i.e.: slimming down Page Type to bare minimum allows page to be created.

Increasing  in  TRIDION_HOME%\config\Tridion.ContentManager.config didn't help so far (as well as similar advices here at SE about raising timeouts and message size limits).

I'm guessing there must be something interesting in an input to *FastTrackPublishingService.Preview*. But my customer won't accept complains on data. So i'd rather wanted to know what limits should be raised to work around this situation?

Comment: If you suspect it's due to size, then probably there's something going on about the maximum POST size allowed by your webapp container for the OData service.

Comment: Thanks Nuno, could you please clarify: is it (OData) Preview service that is performing POST requests? Does this picture depicts general flow correctly: https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/1rOt4Bqy2jMw2KLBfckB_-dmyM45ps3BohuamgdTIkDo/edit?usp=sharing?

Comment: Yes, the Fast Track Publishing will POST to OData.